# plt legend color not shown

Tags: matplotlib, legend

'''

```
import umap
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
reducer=umap.UMAP()
out_training=pd.read_csv('C:/Users/samsung/Downloads/상하수도 데이터(상수관로 누수 감지)/Training/누수감지데이터셋(Training)/1.옥외누수(out-training).csv')
in_training=pd.read_csv('C:/Users/samsung/Downloads/상하수도 데이터(상수관로 누수 감지)/Training/누수감지데이터셋(Training)/2.옥내누수(in-training).csv')
noise_training=pd.read_csv('C:/Users/samsung/Downloads/상하수도 데이터(상수관로 누수 감지)/Training/누수감지데이터셋(Training)/3.기계.전기음(noise-training).csv')
other_training=pd.read_csv('C:/Users/samsung/Downloads/상하수도 데이터(상수관로 누수 감지)/Training/누수감지데이터셋(Training)/4.환경음(other-training).csv')
normal_training=pd.read_csv('C:/Users/samsung/Downloads/상하수도 데이터(상수관로 누수 감지)/Training/누수감지데이터셋(Training)/5.정상음(normal-training).csv')
concat_training=pd.concat([out_training, in_training, noise_training, other_training, normal_training])
concat_training_difference=concat_training[concat_training.columns.difference(['site','sid','ldate','leaktype'])]

embedding=reducer.fit_transform(concat_training_difference)
print(len(embedding))
cdict={"out":'red', "in":'blue', "noise":'yellow', "other":'orange', "normal":'purple'}



fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for g in np.unique(y_training):
    ix = np.where(y_training == g)
    ax.scatter(embedding[:,0][ix], embedding[:,1][ix], color = cdict[g], label = g, s = 0.001)
ax.legend()
plt.show()
'''
```

[legend_color_not_shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PKpin.png)

The problem in the image is that in the legend, there are no colors shown.
How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the very small dot size (`s = 0.001`).  You can set a markerscale when creating the legend:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(np.random.randn(100000).cumsum(), np.random.randn(100000).cumsum(), s=0.001, color='tomato', label='red')
ax.scatter(np.random.randn(100000).cumsum(), np.random.randn(100000).cumsum(), s=0.001, color='lime', label='green')
ax.scatter(np.random.randn(100000).cumsum(), np.random.randn(100000).cumsum(), s=0.001, color='skyblue', label='blue')
ax.legend(markerscale=200)
plt.show()
```

[image: scatter plot with small dots and markerscale in legend]

Comment: Yes!! Thanks a lot for your time and answer..